# making articles show in columns laravel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

im new to laravel im currently trying to show my articles in columns of two however they are showing in individual rows stacked on top of each other. any help would be great as this is frustrating ! lol

```
@extends('layouts.application')
@section('page_title', 'All stories')
@section('content')
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @forelse($stories as $story)
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/polygonal-lion-head_23-2147495868.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
                    <h3>{{ $story->title }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ str_limit($story->body, 217) }}</p>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="/posts/{{ $story->id }}" class="btn btn-latest pull-right">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @empty
            <h1>Currently no stories!</h1>
            @endforelse
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
@include('includes/_rightmenu')
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the < div class="col-md-6" > inside the loop try the below:

```
@extends('layouts.application')
@section('page_title', 'All stories')
@section('content')
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="row">

        @forelse($stories as $story)
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/polygonal-lion-head_23-2147495868.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
                    <h3>{{ $story->title }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ str_limit($story->body, 217) }}</p>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="/posts/{{ $story->id }}" class="btn btn-latest pull-right">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @empty
        <h1>Currently no stories!</h1>
        @endforelse
</div>
</div>
<br>
@include('includes/_rightmenu')
@endsection
```

Should do the trick

Comment: this didnt seem to do trick , well it did but now as the layout is currently set to <div class="col-md-8></div><div class="col-md-4></div> with articles show as 2 per row in col-8 however after adding your change it has caused it all to go down

Comment: Your trying to get 2 rows in the col-md-8?

Comment: basically im using bootstrap and the grid is using 8/4 with the 8 section holding two columns so each column will show article in it, with the other grind column has right menu

Comment: My bad, I think there was an extra </div> ive edited the answer if you try again should be good

Comment: however its now stacking everything all over place and the content set within col-4 of the grid is now displaying under articles

Comment: No probs :) glad could help

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a bootstrap question. Bootstrap allows a maximum of 12 columns. To design the column first create a container, create a row and add the desired number of columns

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2"> Add something here.
          </div>
             <div class="col-sm-3">This in the next column.
           </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">This in the next column.
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

In your case, `<div class="col-sm-*">` inside loop.where * is any number of columns you want in that row.

Comment: ive done this 8/4  equals 12 and with the articles set within 6/6 of column 8

Comment: @Daniel tag the question with 'twitter-bootstrap-3' and you'll get more suggestions.